# SharePoint 2013 get user groups by CSOM

Tags: 2013, javascript, groups, client-object-model, user

I wrote some code to get the current user groups by CSOM.

```
function getCurrentUser() {
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.load(allGroups);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededUser), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedUser));
}
function onQuerySucceededUser() {
    //debugger;
    var groups = currentUser.get_groups();
    var groupsEnum = groups.getEnumerator();
    while (groupsEnum.moveNext()) {
        //handle group
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

on this line: `groups.getEnumerator();`

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move this line

```
var groups = currentUser.get_groups();
```

To your `getCurrentUser` method and make sure to load it

```
this.clientContext.load(groups);
```

before executing the request, this way you will have it loaded in your success-function

Answer (score 4):

```
The code should look like this:

    function getCurrentUser() {
        this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
        this.allGroups = currentUser.get_groups();    
        clientContext.load(allGroups);
        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededUser), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedUser));
    }
    function onQuerySucceededUser() {
        var groupsEnum = allGroups.getEnumerator();
        while (groupsEnum.moveNext()) {

        //handle group
        var group = groupsEnum.get_current();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could y please add the line: var group = groupsEnum.get_current(); I lost 1 hout into this